# Has this integral got a solution?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I was looking for a family of functions, $f_{n}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ with pointwise convergence to some function $f$ such that    $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_ndt\neq\int_{0}^{1}fdt$.

Taking $f=1$ and $f_{n}=e^{2\pi it^{n}}$ satisfies the pointwise convergence...but I have no idea what is going on with the integral $\int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi it^{n}}dt$. Wolfram Alpha refused to say anything productive, does the limit of this integral as $n\to\infty$ exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $f_n$ being uniformly bounded on $[0,1]$, the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem will tell you that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\; dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\; dx$

For a counterexample, you'll want functions that are not uniformly bounded.  If you don't want a "piecewise" function, you might try
$$ f_n(x) = n^2 x \exp(-n x) $$

[EDIT]
As for your integral, you can write
$$ \exp(2\pi i t^n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2 \pi i)^k t^{nk}}{k!}$$
so that
$$ \int_0^1 \exp(2 \pi i t^n)\; dt = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi i)^k}{k!\;(nk+1)} $$
The summation can be expressed using Laguerre functions or hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $\exp(t^n)$ has no elementary antiderivative. So, why do not you look at something simple to integrate, like $$f_n(x)=n\chi_{(0, 1/n)}(x)$$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function on the set $A.$

Answer (score 0):

By [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), as
$$
\|f_n(t)\|=1
$$
you have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(t) dt= \int_0^1 \lim_n f_n(t)=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the question you really care about.

Let $f_n(x)$ be $0$ outside the interval $[1/2n, 1/n]$ and inside that interval the constant that makes the integral $1$ - namely, $2n$.

That sequence of functions converges pointwise to $0$.

You could modify this example so that the functions are continuous, but there is no example with bounded functions.

By including the actual question you sidestepped the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

What about $f_n(x)=n, x\in (0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x)=0, x=0 $ or $x\in (1/n,1]$?

Clearly $f_n\to 0$ but $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=1$ for all $n\geq 1$.